# Python gnupg encrypt_file(StringIO()) creates encrypted PGP message with empty content?

Tags: python, encryption, gnupg

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here. As far as I can tell from the python gnupg documentation this `encrypt_file` call should have content like the `encrypt` call, but everything I'm trying is resulting in a GPG blob that decrypts to a blank file. No error, no indication that there was any problem with the operation, just... emptyness, like it was compiled with sartre=1...

Am I missing some key to the incantation?

Python 3.6.5,
python-gnupg==0.4.7

```
from gnupg import GPG
from io import StringIO

gpg = GPG(gpgbinary='/usr/local/bin/gpg', gnupghome='/tmp/gpg/')
keyserver = <insert keyserver URI>
fp = <insert GPG key fingerprint>
gpg.recv_keys(keyserver, fp)

sio = StringIO('\n'.join([f"Hello world {n}" for n in range(120)]))

c0 = gpg.encrypt(sio.getvalue(), recipients=fp)
len(str(c0))
1252

c1 = gpg.encrypt_file(sio, recipients=fp)
len(str(c1))
858

sio = StringIO('\n'.join([f"Hello world {n}" for n in range(1200)]))

c0 = gpg.encrypt(sio.getvalue(), recipients=fp)
len(str(c0))
4559

c1 = gpg.encrypt_file(sio, recipients=fp)
len(str(c1))
858
```

Comment: Is this just an excerpt, or is this the whole transcript?  Remember that, when treating a StringIO as a file, it has a file position.  If you had done `sio.read()`, that would leave the pointer at end-of-file and `encrypt_file` would get nothing.  Try doing `sio.seek(0)` before the `encrypt_file` calls.

Comment: Tim, thanks - see my answer below - that was part of it. I still can't get any content in the GPG file when I use a text file-like object, which seems odd.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the following were the operative issues:

- The file-like object, it seems, has to be binary; e.g. a `BytesIO` or a file pointer opened in binary mode.
- You have to `seek(0)` to write the full content of the file-like object. *(Kind of obvious but I overlooked it; I probably kept checking `encrypt()` first then `encrypt_file()` without seeking back to the start. It probably didn't help that this doesn't make it work on a StringIO, so I may have mentally ruled it out as the issue early on.)*